# UPDATE OUTPUT into a variable

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to perform an update and a select ... basically, update based on an index, and then select the row id that was updated.

This is simple using the OUTPUT clause:

```
UPDATE Foo
SET Bar = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
WHERE Baz = 2
```

But now, how do I get this into a variable?

```
DECLARE @id INT
```

These three don't work:

```
UPDATE Foo
SET Bar = 1
OUTPUT @id = INSERTED.Id
WHERE Baz = 2

SET @id =
(UPDATE Foo
 SET Bar = 1
 OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
 WHERE Baz = 2)

SET @id =
(SELECT Id FROM (UPDATE Foo
                 SET Bar = 1
                 OUTPUT INSERTED.Id Id
                 WHERE Baz = 2) z)
```

That last one included because it had me temporarily excited when all the red squigglies went away in Management Studio. Alas, I get this error:

```
A nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement is not allowed in a SELECT statement that is not the immediate source of rows for an INSERT statement.
```

Answer (score 119, accepted):

If only one row is affected, it can be done without a table variable.

```
DECLARE @id INT

UPDATE Foo 
SET Bar = 1, @id = id 
WHERE Baz = 2

SELECT @id
```

Comment: I've never even thought of this. Very nice!

Comment: Thanks Cory, I wondered if the set keyword inside the update will be able to set a variable and it worked!

Comment: will this work with `insert` for a single affected row?

Comment: No @rahoolm, only the `SET` and `SELECT` keywords can modify a variable and these keywords cannot be used with `INSERT` statement

Comment: How do I do this in a delete query ?

Comment: This does not work with Insert and Delete statements @Shanid.

Comment: There are some limits to this approach; for example, if you have a rowversion column, this will return the *last* rowversion, not the one resulting from your update.

Answer (score 107):

Because an update can affect multiple rows, it requires a table to store its results:

```
declare @ids table (id int);

UPDATE Foo
SET Bar = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO @ids
WHERE Baz = 2
```

If you're sure only one row will be affected, you can pull out the id like:

```
declare @id int
select  top 1 @id = id
from    @ids
```

Comment: You don't have to have a table for the results. You can do this:  OUPUT INSERTED.*  Of course this will bring back all the cols though.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, If only one row is being affected:

```
DECLARE @id INT

UPDATE Foo 
SET @id = Bar = 1  ---Yes, this is valid!
WHERE Baz = 2

SELECT @id
```