# Why my update stored procedure return 2 rows affected while there's only one data in table?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a strored procedure that can update tables in two different databases.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Update]
(
    @sID        VARCHAR(max),
    @sName      VARCHAR(max),
    @sLocation  VARCHAR(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    -- Update table1 in database testDB1 --
    UPDATE dbo.table1 SET Name = @sName, Location = @sLocation WHERE ID = @sID

    -- Update table2 in database testDB2 --
    UPDATE testDB2.dbo.table2 SET Name = @sName, Location = @sLocation WHERE ID = @sID

END
```

`table2` contains all data in `table1` but not all data in `table1` contains in `table2`.

So, If there's some data in `table1` that updated, automatically `table2` also updated and if no data in `table1` updated, `table2` still updated.

There's no error in my queries actually, when I'm tried to update data that only in `table2`, it returns

> (0 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

But, every time I tried update data in both tables, it returns

> (2 row(s) affected)
>
> (1 row(s) affected)

So, why its said 2 rows affected when there's only one data on `table1`?

Comment: First question, are dbo.table1 the one you want to update? I ask because you are specifying the database in table2 (`testDB2.dbo.table2`); Second question have you tried to run a select (`select .... where id=[the id you passed as parm]`) command with those parameters on table1 and 2 and see what it returns?

Comment: @JorgeCampos 1st, if there's data that can be updated in both tables, the data in both table updated, but if there's data in `table2` but no in `table1` only `table2` updated.
2nd, I've tried that and each tables return one data.

Comment: There is no mystery bug here. You need to take a good look at your data and understand why two rows were updated. I suggest you use OUTPUT to capture what was updated, or you could even just select it in your SP  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847297/update-output-into-a-variable

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid it returns two rows because in `table1` has two data with one of them is not usable anymore. I need to add more condition so it will return one row