# Retrieve value of a column after update?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac

I update a counter (no autoincrement ... not my database ...) with this FDQuery SQL:

```
UPDATE CountersTables
SET Cnter = Cnter + 1
OUTPUT Inserted.Cnter
WHERE TableName = 'TableName'
```

I execute FDQuery.ExecSQL and it works: 'Cnter' is incremented.

I need to retrieve the new 'Counter' value but the subsequent command

```
newvalue := FDQuery.FieldByName('Cnter').AsInteger
```

Fails with error:

> ... EDatabaseError ... 'CountersTables: Field 'Cnter' not found.

What is the way to get that value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TFDQuery.ExecSQL()` is meant for queries that *don't* return records. But you are asking your query to return a record. So use `TFDQuery.Open()` instead, eg:

```pascal
FDQuery.SQL.Text :=
  'UPDATE CountersTables' +
  ' SET Cnter = Cnter + 1' +
  ' OUTPUT Inserted.Cnter' +
  ' WHERE TableName = :TableName';
FDQuery.ParamByName('TableName').AsString := 'TableName';
FDQuery.Open;
try
  NewValue := FDQuery.FieldByName('Cnter').AsInteger;
finally
  FDQuery.Close;
end;
```

If the database you are connected to does not support `OUTPUT`, [UPDATE OUTPUT into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16847297/) shows some alternative ways you can save the updated counter into a local SQL variable/table that you can then `SELECT` from.

Answer (score 0):

You have also the [RETURNING Unified support](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/RETURNING_Unified_Support_(FireDAC)) Ok, doc only shows INSERT SQL but UPDATE works too.
And I should use a [substitution variable](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)) for tablename

Comment: Thanks. Your answer too is useful.
Remy was only faster ... :)

Comment: I guess it comes down to which kind of database is being accessed. Different engines offer different SQL features.